# Loop won't finish...Poor indentation?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

I am new to python and Jupyter Notebook

The objective of the code I am writing is to request the user to introduce 10 different integers. The program is supposed to return the highest odd number introduced previously by the user.

My code is as followws:

```
  i=1
  c=1
  y=1

  while i<=10:
  c=int(input('Enter an integer number: '))

    if c%2==0:
        print('The number is even')
    elif c> y
        y=c
        print('y')

    i=i+1
```

My loop is running over and over again, and I don't get a solution.
I guess the code is well written. It must be a slight detail I am not seeing.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean my running over and over again with no solution? the code as written won't run because of a missing colon on `elif c>y` but if you add that it seems to run fine is there some other issues?

Comment: You can do it in a much more compact fashion. Check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

You have `elif c > y`, you should just need to add a colon there so it's `elif c > y:`

Answer (score 0):

Yup.

```
  i=1
  c=1
  y=1

  while i<=10:
    c=int(input('Enter an integer number: ')) # This line was off 

    if c%2==0:
        print('The number is even')
    elif c> y: # Need also ':' 
        y=c
        print('y')

    i=i+1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can right this in a much compact fashion like so.

Start by asking for 10 numbers in a single line, separated by a space. Then  split the string by `,` into a list of numbers and exit the code if exactly 10 numbers are not provided.

```
numbers_str = input("Input 10 integers separated by a comma(,) >>> ")
numbers = [int(number.strip()) for number in numbers_str.split(',')]
if len(numbers) != 10:
    print("You didn't enter 10 numbers! try again")
    exit()
```

A bad run of the code above might be

```
Input 10 integers separated by a comma(,) >>> 1,2,3,4
You didn't enter 10 numbers! try again
```

Assuming 10 integers are provided, loop through the elements, considering only odd numbers and updating highest odd number as you go.

```
largest = None
for number in numbers:
    if number % 2 != 0 and (not largest or number > largest):
        largest = number
```

Finally, check if the largest number is None, which means we didn't have any odd numbers, so provide the user that information, otherwise display the largest odd number

```
if largest is None:
    print("You didn't enter any odd numbers")
else:
    print("Your largest odd number was:", largest)
```

Possible outputs are

```
Input 10 integers separated by a comma(,) >>> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
Your largest odd number was: 9
```

```
Input 10 integers separated by a comma(,) >>> 2,4,6,8,2,4,6,8,2,4
You didn't enter any odd numbers
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response...but the cell is still not running...it is still not asking to introduce any number. When I hit run, the blue asterisk is displayed on the left of the cell. What is happening?

Comment: What do you mean by `the blue asterisk is displayed on the left of the cell` I didn't get it!

Comment: However there is still a problem since the output in each iteration of an odd number is the letter y rather than being the last largest odd number

Comment: You mean in my solution?